# get only third line data of a file in android

Tags: android

In my android app i am reading a file but require anly the data on third line to be displayed.Is there any way to do that.

Please forward your suggestion:)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to be too specious, but.....

```
String str = InputStream.readline();
str = InputStream.readline();
str = InputStream.readline();
```

Now you have your string ;)

Just be happy that you don't need the thousandth string.  (of course, enclosing this is a parameterized for loop would solve that problem)

Comment: Thanks Kevin.Its working but is there any way that i can even set or replace the same line with some other data.

Comment: That requires reading the entire file and when you get to the desired line, write the new value, not the old value.